# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object' error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and i have been trying to display some data in the website.
But all i am getting is error

Here is my code snippet.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
this.loggeduser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
console.log(this.loggeduser)
this.customer_id = this.loggeduser[0].CUSTOMER_ID
console.log(this.customer_id)

this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/getAdminOrders', JSON.stringify({ 'id': this.customer_id }), { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) }).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log("res", res)
  this.stored = res
  console.log(this.stored)
  // for (let x = 0; x < this.stored.length; x++) {
  //   this.stored[x].PURCHASE_DATE = new Date(this.stored[x].PURCHASE_DATE)
  // }
})
```

Here's the template content.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-secondary">
                        <th scope="col">Product</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Order Placed</th>
                        <th scope="col">Order Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Payment Mode</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr *ngFor="let stores of stored">
                        <td>
                            <div class="media">
                                <!-- image -->
                                <div class="d-flex">
                                  <img src="http://localhost:3000/{{stores.PRODUCT_IMAGE}}" height="150px" alt="">
                              </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h5>{{stores.PRODUCT_PURCHASED}}</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h5>{{stores.PRODUCT_PRICE | currency: "&#8377;"}}</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:20%;">
                            <h5>{{stores.PURCHASE_DATE| date: 'MMM d, y'}}&nbsp;{{stores.PURCHASE_TIME}}</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h5>{{stores.ORDER_ID}}</h5>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:14%">
                            <h5>{{stores.PAYMENT_MODE}}</h5>
                        </td>



                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

I can see the data that is fetched from the backend in the console.
[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error --> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. I can see the data in the console but the its not getting displayed in the website

Comment: You have many data. so which data you saw in the console?

Comment: Every data form customer_name,id, purchase details and  order details

Comment: How did you try to display these data?

Comment: Its getting displayed under the table tag of html. Also I have attached a screenshot of error for the convenience.

Comment: Let's attach your template content.

Comment: @hoangdv  I have attached the template code

Comment: Change `<tr *ngFor="let stores of stored">` to `<tr *ngIf="stored && stored.lenght" *ngFor="let stores of stored">`

Comment: Its giving this error  Can't have multiple template bindings on one element

Comment: Apply ngIf for tbody `<tbody *ngIf="stored && stored.lenght">`

Comment: Thanks the error got resolved. But the data is still not getting displayed in the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues. First, your property names are not capital. It should match the same case sensitivity like this

```
 <h5>{{stores.Product_Purchased}}</h5>
```

the error was caused because of the image values. since image data return an array you either need to loop it through `ngFor` or access it through index

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/{{stores.Product_Image.data[0]}}" height="150px" alt="">
```